# How to make spring data @Async work? Error: PersistentEntity must not be null

Tags: java, spring-data

When I try to use @Async on a Spring Data Repository method I get the following error:

{"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}

As if it tries to serialize CompletableFuture<>.

The repository code:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Produto p where descricao LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(:like),'%')")
@Async
CompletableFuture<List<Produto>> findByLikeAsync(@Param("like") String like);
```

The configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"..."})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"..."})
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class Application implements AsyncConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

I have tried to use Future<> instead of CompletableFuture<>, but it throws the same error.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does "Persistent entity must not be null" make you think it's trying to serialize a `CompletableFuture`? The stacktrace should tell you where the *real* error is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `CrudRepository`, methods in the repository can only return the class that they're registered for (or collections of them). In this case, if you have defined your repository to be:

`public interface ProdutoRepository extends CrudRepository<Produto, Long>`

You have to return `List<Produto>`. You can create a `@Service` that calls this and have a public method there annotated with `@Async`.

Comment: I am calling the Async method directly. I must be doing something wrong. I just started learning spring, maybe I misconcepted something.